# is linear combination unique for each vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, combinations, linear-programming, direct-sum

each vector $\vec x$∈$R^n$ can be expressed as a sum
$$\vec x = \vec x_1\vec e_1+···+\vec x_n\vec e_n$$
Show that this expression is unique, that is, there does not exist other, different linear combination of vectors $$\vec e_1,\vec e_2,...,\vec e_n$$ which is equal to $\vec x$.
I've test vector $$\begin{bmatrix}16 \\32 \\\end{bmatrix} = 1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\\end{bmatrix} + 2\begin{bmatrix}8 \\16 \\\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}16 \\32 \\\end{bmatrix} = 2\begin{bmatrix}2 \\8 \\\end{bmatrix} + 4\begin{bmatrix}3 \\4 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
and wrote it in such different ways. So I don't get what's happening here, is not this against uniqueness? Or if I am wrong then give me some hints how to prove it.

Comment: What are $e_1$?

Comment: @spinosarus123 I don't know, I think it's normal vector as it's not defined in exercise.

Comment: @spinosarus123 in the textbook there was defined $e_1$ in such way: vector with first component 1 and other n - 1 with 0, $e_2$ with second component 1 and other n - 1 with 0 and so on... but I don't know if the same e is used in exercise.

Comment: First of all the coefficient of $[1\ 1]^T$ must be zero, not $1$. The issue is that you changed the basis. Originally $\vec e_1=[1\ 1]^T$, then $\vec e_1=[2\ 8]^T$. In your test case, you want to show that $[16\ 32]=\alpha[1\ 1]+\beta[8\ 16]$  has a unique solution $\alpha=0,\beta=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement means that for a *given* basis of linearly independent vectors $\vec e_1, \dots, \vec e_n$ there is a unique decomposition of any vector $\vec x$ into a linear combination $\vec x = x_1\vec e_1 + \dots + x_n \vec e_n$. Note that $x_i$ are not vectors, but real numbers: coordinates of the vector $\vec x$ in the basis $\vec e_1, \dots, \vec e_n$.

In your example you considered two different bases, so of course the coordinates are different.

Comment: so you are saying that the statement is correct, aren't you? I understand now what I must prove.